# while i am entering text in one field it is diplaying same text in some other textfield too

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

When I am entering text in textfield 1 that text is also displayed in textfield 9.

here is some code what i did to create textfield in tableview cell.

i added textfield in tableview cell .like below in cellforRowatintexpath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";
//UILabel* nameLabel = nil;
cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil)
{

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
else
{
    UILabel *titleLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [titleLbl removeFromSuperview];
}
nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 7.0, 10.0, 160.0, 44.0 )];
nameLabel.text = [labels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]; 
nameLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
nameLabel.tag =1;
nameLabel.numberOfLines =0;
[nameLabel sizeToFit];
CGSize expectedlabelsize = [nameLabel.text sizeWithFont:nameLabel.font constrainedToSize:nameLabel.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGRect newFrame =nameLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height =expectedlabelsize.height;
[cell.contentView addSubview: nameLabel];
[nameLabel release]; 


//adding textfield to tableview cell. 
tv = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(nameLabel.frame.origin.x+nameLabel.frame.size.width+2, 10.0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
tv.tag = indexPath.row + 2;
//tv.text =[labels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
tv.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];


//this method will take text from textfield of tableview cell using their individual tag
[tv addTarget:self action:@selector(getTextFieldValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];

[cell.contentView addSubview:tv];

[tv setDelegate:self];


[tv release];   


return cell;}
```

and here is the method getTextFieldValue method

```
- (void) getTextFieldValue:(UITextField *)textField{ 

if (textField.tag == 2) { 

    //NSString *value1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text];
    //NSLog(@"value1 is %@",value1);.

    NSLog(@"2--->%@",textField.text); 
}else if(textField.tag == 3){ 
    NSLog(@"3--->%@",textField.text); 
}else if(textField.tag == 4){ 
    NSLog(@"4--->%@",textField.text); 
    } 
else if(textField.tag == 5){ 
    NSLog(@"5--->%@",textField.text); 
} 
else if(textField.tag == 6){ 
    NSLog(@"6--->%@",textField.text); 
} 
else if(textField.tag == 7){ 
    NSLog(@"7--->%@",textField.text); 
} 
else if(textField.tag == 8){ 
    NSLog(@"8--->%@",textField.text); 
} 
else if(textField.tag == 9){ 
    NSLog(@"9--->%@",textField.text); 
} 
else if(textField.tag == 10){ 
    NSLog(@"10--->%@",textField.text); 
} 
else if(textField.tag == 11){ 
        NSLog(@"11--->%@",textField.text); 
} 
else if(textField.tag == 12){ 
        NSLog(@"12--->%@",textField.text); 
} }
```

Comment: while i am entering  text in one textfield it displayed in multiple textfield .....

Comment: now my question is clear to you

Comment: what is the problem if i am reusing cell

Comment: Can you post the complete cellForRowAtIndexPath function?

Comment: yes i added complete cellForRowAtIndexPath function check it out

Comment: @Rengers check it out i updated code .........

Comment: Maybe you have set some IBOutlet to the textField. Did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the retain problem is there.

You can take different cellIdentifier for each row. Only change one statement you get your solution.

Solve this problem with above method. i was facing same problem & i solve with this method.
I hope this will help you.

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cellidentifier-%d",indexPath.row];
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this sucks badly. This will not reuse any cell and _will_ degrade performance! Please Jasmit, don't give answers unless you know what is going on. Even if you wanted to avoid cell reuse, this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: @Rengers : Please tell me what can i do for this type of solution?

Comment: If you really don't want to reuse cells, you can just remove the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call. If you do want to reuse cell (which you probably do), you need to set up the cell structure when creating a cell. Then when reusing it, you only 'reset' the interface and assign cell specifics.

Comment: @iosDev : Please remove the this accepted answer. Because i fill it is wrong then i will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please rewrite your getTextFieldValue method like this:

```
- (void)getTextFieldValue:(UITextField *)textField { 
    NSLog(@"%d--->%@", textField.tag, textField.text); 
}
```

You keep adding UITextFields to the cell, even when it's reused. Try putting that code inside the if statement.

You should set the text of the text field to nil every time though. Else it will still be there on dequeued cells (when scrolling).

Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";
cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 7.0, 10.0, 160.0, 44.0 )];
    //TODO: Set up nameLabel here
    [cell.contentView addSubview: nameLabel];
    [nameLabel release];

    UITextField *tv = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    tv.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    [tv setDelegate:self];
    [tv addTarget:self action:@selector(getTextFieldValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tv];
    [tv release];
}

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
nameLabel.text = [labels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[nameLabel sizeToFit];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have set some IBOutlet to the textField? Did you?